# Switch lib to be imported python

Tags: python, python-import

I have two libs with same packages inside.
For example,

```
lib1
   p1
   p2
lib2
   p1
   p2
```

And I want to import one of them in main code and make switching libs easy.

It's possible to make `lib.py` with code

```
from lib1.p1 import * 
from lib1.p2 import *
```

and then write in main code `from lib import *`.

And then I can change the text of `lib.py` only.

It works fine, but I want to use package name for calling functions.
Call them in main code like `p1.f()` or `lib.p1.f()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What actual problem are you trying to solve? A simple solution would be `current = lib1; current.p.f1(); current = lib2; current.p.f1()`

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I can import the  and reassign in ui module: ```import ui.ui_pyqt.graphics; graphics = ui.ui_pyqt.graphics```. Or ```.ui_pygame.```. And then ```import ui.graphics``` anyware. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be

```
current = lib1
current.p.f1()
...
current = lib2
current.p.f1()
```

Comment: Your solution requires changes in main code, which use the libraries. Doesn't it?

Comment: "Changes" as in, yes, the places where you wanted to switch which library you use obviously needs to implement that change somehow.

Comment: using the answer above in comments make possible switch lib by changing one file in project only [](https://ibb.co/h92r3xw)

Comment: This is identical to what I provided in a comment.

Comment: Understood. The first line in config, the second in all other files.

Comment: I'm sorry, your comments don't make any sense. Your question mentions nothing about a configuration file. This is a minimal example based on what you actually asked; if your real-life world scenario is more complex, by all means adapt the solution to that. In the meantime, I would expect you to accept this answer to mark the question as resolved, or else leave a comment explaining why this does not satisfy your original requirements. I originally only left a comment because I thought you probably meant to ask something else, but you responded that this was exactly what you needed.